# mg graph 2.0.0 update causing issues in azure devops release pipelines. Invoke-MgGraphRequest : Method not found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

```ps1
$context = Get-AzContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$secureAccessToken = $graphToken | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $secureAccessToken
Get-InstalledModule Microsoft.Graph

$UserReadAllId = Find-MgGraphPermission User.Read.All -ExactMatch -PermissionType Application | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id
write-host $UserReadAllId
```

```
Error record:
Invoke-MgGraphRequest : Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Graph.Authentication.AzureIdentityAccessTokenProvider..ctor(Azure.Core.TokenCredential, System.String[], Microsoft.Kiota.Authentication.Azure.ObservabilityOptions, System.String[])'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Microsoft.Graph.Authentication\2.0.0\custom\common\Permissions.ps1:37 char:27
+ ... estResult = Invoke-MgGraphRequest -method GET -OutputType PSObject $_ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-MgGraphRequest], MissingMethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSpecified,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Authentication.Cmdlets.InvokeMgGraphRequest
 
Script stack trace:
at Permissions_GetPermissionsData, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Microsoft.Graph.Authentication\2.0.0\custom\common\Permissions.ps1: line 37
at Find-MgGraphPermission<Begin>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Microsoft.Graph.Authentication\2.0.0\custom\Find-MgGraphPermission.ps1: line 202
```

Is someone else facing these issues? This started from 12 july 23. I tried explicitly installing 1.27.0 version but still no luck.
Please let me know if you are able to connect-mggraph in devops release pipeline

Comment: Did you update to SDK 2.0 or is it a new installation? I would try to remove the Microsoft.Graph module and install it again

Comment: I checked the version of mg-graph in the pipeline and it is 2.0.0. Tried explicitly uninstalling the 2.0.0 and installing the 1.28.0 but its takes a lot of time.

Comment: I think that version 2.1.0 has been released recently: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/releases/tag/2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -RequiredVersion 2.1.0 -Force -AllowClobber
```

updating the mg-graph to v2.1.0 has resolved this issue.