# Error: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Graph.Authentication.AzureIdentityAccessTokenProvider..ctor

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Hello guys I am getting this error. Can someone assist me?
My code is this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $userObjectID = (Get-MgUser -Filter "(UserPrincipalName eq '$username')").Id
```

Error:

```
Get-MgUser : Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Graph.Authentication.AzureIdentityAccessTokenProvider..ctor(Azure.Core.TokenCredential, System.String[], 
Microsoft.Kiota.Authentication.Azure.ObservabilityOptions, System.String[])'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $userObjectID = (Get-MgUser -Filter "(UserPrincipalName eq '$username ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-MgUser_List], MissingMethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetMgUser_List`
```

Comment: Hi @Panagiotis Kontogiannis Can you share your `Microsoft.Graph` module version?

Answer (score 0):

> Get-MgUser : Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Graph.Authentication.AzureIdentityAccessTokenProvider..ctor(Azure.Core.TokenCredential,System.String[],
> Microsoft.Kiota.Authentication.Azure.ObservabilityOptions, System.Str

The above error message indicates that some parameters are missing in **`Microsoft.Graph.Authentication.AzureIdentityAccessTokenProvider`** due to a version mismatch between the **`Microsoft Graph SDK`** and the **`Azure Identity SDK.`**

You can refer to this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76677136/mg-graph-2-0-0-update-causing-issues-in-azure-devops-release-pipelines-invoke-m)  by Shahid Sayyed.

In my environment, I installed the latest version **`Microsoft-graph SDK version-2.9.0`** module by using the below command:

**Command:**

```
 Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -RequiredVersion 2.9.0 -Force -AllowClobber
```

After installation check with **`Get-module`** command.

**Output:**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     2.12.1     Az.Accounts                         {Add-AzEnvironment, Clear-AzConfig, Clear-AzContext, Clear-AzDefault...}
Script     2.9.0      Microsoft.Graph.Authentication      {Add-MgEnvironment, Connect-MgGraph, Disconnect-MgGraph, Get-MgContext...}
Script     2.9.0      Microsoft.Graph.Users               {Get-MgUser, Get-MgUserCount, Get-MgUserCreatedObject, Get-MgUserCreatedObjectAsServicePrincipal...}
```

After installing it in my environment, I tried the same command and it executed successfully.

**Command:**

```
Connect-MgGraph
$username="<Your-userprinicipal-name>" 
$userObjectID = (Get-MgUser -Filter "(UserPrincipalName eq '$username')").Id 
$userObjectID
```

**Output:**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $username="vxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $userObjectID = (Get-MgUser -Filter "(UserPrincipalName eq '$username')").Id
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $userObjectID
ef2746a6-f0e3-4b67-bde8-xxxxxf9
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[PowerShell Gallery | Microsoft.Graph.Authentication 2.9.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Authentication/2.9.0)